# Cannot enter "n" in contact app

Tags: contacts

I am using the German Kontakte app in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Whenever I try to add a name or an address containing the letter "n" the keypress is simply ignored. Obviously this means I cannot use the app in its present form. Does anyone have a solution or an alternative app?

Answer (score 1):

So, after looking around I installed gnome-contacts from via Synaptic and the version of Kontakte installed with that (3.36.1) worked. But my activity button showed  two versions of Kontakte alongside each other. One working and one not.

I did a `whereis gnome-contacts` in a terminal and found out that the old one was a snap-app. So I did `sudo snap remove gnome-contacts` and that removed it.

Now I only have a working gnome-contacts version 3.36.1, installed via Synaptic, on my laptop.